# jQuery append template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I'm trying to insert some template with jQuery and get two different results when I'm using:

a)

```
var $template = $("#productTemplate").html();
```

b)

```
var $template = $($("#productTemplate").html());
```

If I use a) case I can add template many times, if I use b) I can add template only one time.
So what is the difference?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


<div class="but">
    <a href="#" class="showForm"> Click </a>
</div>


<script id='productTemplate' type='text/template'>
    <div class="product">
        <h1>H1</h1>
    </div>
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    var $template = $($("#productTemplate").html());

    $(".showForm").on("click",function() {
        $("body").append($template);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 4):

In (a) `$template` is a string, and `.append($template)` will always create a new DOM fragment, based on the string, before appending.

In (b) `$template` is an object, because `$(HTML_String)` returns `jQuery`, and `.append($template)` will always use the same object - re-appending it will move it around in the DOM. To reuse `$template`, you need to explicitly `.clone()` it before appending.

Answer (score 1):

"My guess": Probably when you load your $template object outsite the click handler, jQuery identifies you are trying to append the same jQuery objet, and then jQuery doesn't append. If you load your variable again, it works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".showForm").on("click", function() {
    var $template = $($("#productTemplate").html()); //inside the click handler works
    $("body").append($template);
  });
});
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/L19RGOKeQXYYkvOuBbX7?p=preview

EDIT:

The difference between the two options is that the b) you can manipulate like an already DOM element, i.e., you can do something like:

```
$template.find("#my_hidden_id").val("12");
$template.find("#another_div").append("<p>Another html</p>");
```

and then append your new custom template...